# WPF Wrappanel nicely aligned Textblocks and Textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wrappanel

I have been banging my head for a few hours trying to figure out how can I have my textblocks and textboxes aligned in a Wrappanel. I have tried everything that I could find on stackoverflow but the truth is this in my first WPF app and I am having a hard time figuring things out.

What I am trying to achieve is described in detail in this post but I couldn't get it to work using the steps outlined here: http://badecho.com/2012/07/wpf-grid-like-wrappanels/

Here's what I have so far:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="10,150,0,10"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
<TabItem Header="Repairs">

<Grid Margin="0,0,10,0">

    <WrapPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,10,10">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="20, 5, 0, 20">
         Regular Paid Hours
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="20, 0, 10, 20" Width="45"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="20, 5, 0, 20">
         Overtime Hours
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="20, 0, 10, 20" Width="45"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="20, 5, 0, 20">
         Repair Labor
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="20, 0, 10, 20" Width="45"></TextBox>\

        <!-- There are a lot more -->  
    </WrapPanel>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource lowCase}" Margin="20,180,10,70" Name="dtGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserResizeRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" GridLinesVisibility="All">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Location}" Header="Location"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat ='MM-dd-yy'}" Header="Date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RegularPaidHours}" Header="Regular Repair Hours"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

What I am trying to achieve: Textboxes should be aligned when the window is resized and the datagrid should move down in order to fit all the textblocks and textboxes. What am I missing?

Can someone please offer me a dumbproof solution? I would be so grateful for an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using implicit styles and `HeaderedContentControls`. You can set margins, widths and so on in the `ControlTemplate`. I left it pretty bare-bones. The "InputCol" cell will by default stretch its content horizontally, but you can see in the example how to defeat that for a particular control. "SharedSizeGroup" and "IsSharedSizeScope" on the container are the magic that make all the labels the same width, but no wider than they need to be.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="WrapPanel" x:Key="WrapForm">
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="True" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Implicit style for all HeaderedContentControls -->
            <Style TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LabelCol" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" SharedSizeGroup="InputCol" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                                    />
                                <ContentControl
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource WrapForm}">
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Regular Paid Hours">
            <TextBox />
        </HeaderedContentControl>
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Overtime Hours">
            <TextBox />
        </HeaderedContentControl>
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Repair Labor">
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </HeaderedContentControl>
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="This One Has Two">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <CheckBox>One Thing</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Or Another</CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

### Update

Simple two-row grid layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- 
        This 2* + 1* means "divide the grid vertically into three equal parts,
        and give two of them to row zero and one of them to row one". 
        You could give them both Height="*" and it'll be divided evenly, or 
        make one of them Height="Auto" and it'll get the height it takes up, 
        while the other one will get all the remainder. 
        -->
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer
        Grid.Row="0"
        >
        <WrapPanel 
            Style="{StaticResource WrapForm}"
            >
            <HeaderedContentControl Header="Regular Paid Hours">
                <TextBox />
            </HeaderedContentControl>
            <HeaderedContentControl Header="Overtime Hours">
                <TextBox />
            </HeaderedContentControl>
            <HeaderedContentControl Header="Repair Labor">
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </HeaderedContentControl>
            <HeaderedContentControl Header="This One Has Two">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <CheckBox>One Thing</CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox>Or Another</CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <DataGrid
        Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The Grid here is the main Grid in the Window. It may take some finicking around to get it just the way you want it.

Comment: Ed you are the king of the day!!! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed! I am glad that you were so prompt and your answer is simple yet sophisticated. When I resize the window my textboxes wrap down but they end up behind my datagrid. Can you please help me with some advice so that the datagrid will move with under the wrappanel? What do I need to add?

Comment: @iCosmin Easiest way is to take off the giant margin on the DataGrid and stack the WrapPanel and the DataGrid in a `<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"><WrapPanel ... /><DataGrid ... /></StackPanel>` -- never use margins for layout in WPF, there's always a better option.

Comment: You can also put a ScrollViewer with a MaxHeight around the WrapPanel.

Comment: Adding a ScrollViewer to the WrapPanel works great. However I followed your steps, took the giant margin out and placed the dataGrid inside the StackPanel. My problem now is that I lose the scrollbars on the datagrid. I can only see horizontal one when I maximize. Is there a way in which I can keep both of the scrollbars on the dataGrid? Thank you Ed!

Comment: @iCosmin Hmmm. You know what, a Grid with two rows would be better than the StackPanel. I'll update.

Comment: Excellent response Ed! Thank you for taking the time to doing all this for me and the community. Is there a way to stretch only one of the Textboxes to a different width? My last input box is a Comment box. I can stretch it to the left, inward, using a negative margin. Is there a way to stretch it outwards, more than the fixed width determined by "SharedSizeGroup" and "IsSharedSizeScope" and still have it aligned? Cheers!

Comment: Try MinWidth="120" (or whatever value) on the input column instead of Width. Then you can force it wider by making the control wider. It'll widen every input cell though unless you take off SharedSizeGroup on that second ColumnDefinition

Comment: Thanks you Ed. You really helped me out. Have a great day! :)